# When a member achieves 10k rep, can they see who up/down votes questions/answers?

Tags: discussion

Or does it take Mod status to view those reports?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not even moderators can see who upvoted and downvoted posts. Only some employees can (community managers and developers).

Comment: Oh, OK thanks @Kevin

Comment: Sorry guys, I didn't see the other (same) question.

Comment: If I go to the profile of the user I suspect of downvoting my answer, won't I see the -1 in his/her/their/its recent reputation changes?

Comment: @user14111 - there are other tricks too. Most active voters report helps. Anonymous voting isn't very anonymous once someone starts exibiting voting patterns (like hitting specific users).

Comment: @user14111 No, you won't see the -1 in their profile. Neither will I. You can guess if you see their rep drop by 1 right when you get a downvote, but that's not necessarily accurate.